# How auto justify codes with google code prettify?

Tags: html, google-code-prettify

I use code-prettify and work like a charm
How can I justify codes?

I add this code:

```
<?php
    echo 1;
        echo 1;
    ?>
```

But I want print this:

```
<?php
    echo 1;
    echo 1; //--> remove extra space
?> //--> remove extra space
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google code-prettify is a syntax highlighter, not a code beautifier. Code indentation is usually part of code beautifier.